# Using svn diff command

Tags: linux, svn, diff

Since I'm a newbie to SVN, my question is a bit simple but before asking here, I did look at the official tutorial but the explanation in there did not give me any clue. So I hope I can find someone to simply them for me. Thanks in advance!

Here is my question: how do I use `svn diff` to see differences between a file in my repository and the file that I am currently working on? I mean, the file which is changed after the checkout but has not been added and committed yet.

I've found the commands:

```
diff [-c M | -r N[:M]] [TARGET[@REV]...]

diff [-r N[:M]] --old=OLD-TGT[@OLDREV] [--new=NEW-TGT[@NEWREV]] [PATH...]

diff OLD-URL[@OLDREV] NEW-URL[@NEWREV]
```

but I don't understand what `target[@rev], [--new=NEW-TGT[@NEWREV]] [PATH...]` etc. means.

Assume I checked out the file to `/home/svn/myproject/test.c` and made some changes on it .Now I want to check the one which is on repository and this one. How do I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After making changes to a checked-out file, you can simply run

```
svn diff test.c
```

The `-r` and `@rev` are handy if you want to compare different versions of the file (older revisions). For example, to view the changes made between the two preceding revisions, use

```
svn diff -r PREV:HEAD test.c
```

Comment: thanks for explanation.I do not understand why the  books do not write it like that! :)